# Is there any regular polyhedron that is not of Euler characteristic 2

Tags: graph-theory, polyhedra

Is there any regular polyhedron that 
 1. consist of congruent regular polygons as its faces 
 2. each vertex has same number of adjacent edges

but nonetheless not of characteristic 2? (say, torus or genus?)

If there is any, I would be grateful if you give me its visualization.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Convex polyhedra have Euler characteristic 1. $V-E+F-I$, where $I$ is the interior. The boundary has characteristic 2.

Comment: There is a net for a torus which is made up of seven congruent hexagons all mutually adjacent. If these hexagons are divided into six congruent equilateral triangles, I think you may get what you want.

Answer (score 1):

The five Platonic solids have Euler characteristic $2$ (we are talking about the boundary).  The four Kepler-Poinsot polyhedra [do not all share this property](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kepler%E2%80%93Poinsot_polyhedron#The_Euler_characteristic).  Two have Euler characteristic $-6$, and two have $2$ like the Platonic solids.

Indeed, nonconvex uniform polyhedra can have a variety of values for the Euler characteristic.